# Will computer fan rotate slower if one makes impeller heavier?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, aerodynamics, drag, fan

Imagine that we replace plastic fan [impeller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impeller) with identical metal impeller (same form, heavier weight). Would maximum fan speed decrease?

Common sense suggests that air resistance and bearing friction do not change, but intuitively I would expect fan maximum speed to decrease.

EDIT: As I know, usually computer fans use brushless motors if that matters

Comment: It would probably just take longer (and more energy) to spin- up (i.e. accelerate) to its normal speed.

Comment: Common sense suggests that the bearing coefficient of friction does not change, but in that case the bearing effective friction is proportional to the weight of the load.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Yes, the rotation speed will decrease.

The reason is that the fan gets a constant power (energy per second) from the system which translates to a constant torque that rotate the fan against air resistance (and such). Greater mass density of the fan means greater value of the relevant Tensor of Inertia component of the fan. This means it takes greater force to give it the same amount of angular momentum. On the other way around - for the same amount of force (which can be translated to power mentioned before) it will spin slower.

Comment: I disagree with your analysis. The tensor of Inertia only affects the fan when the angular momentum is changing. Assuming that the fan gets to a steady state, then by definition the angular momentum ISN'T changing.

Comment: If we were living in a frictionless world then you were right. Here you are wrong. When you turn off the powersource the fan stops rotating. Where it's angular momentum gone? The power delivered to the system constantly applies torque to overcome the energy dispersion. As when you drive at constant speed, say 60km/h, and still need to put energy in the system to sustain constant speed.

Comment: That wasn't your argument. I am aware that if mju doesn't change then obviously a higher loading on the bearings would increase friction. But that wasn't what the OP said. The OP said "bearing friction do not change". Nor was it what you said.

Answer (score 4):

If the bearings were to be considered frictionless, then the maximum speed of the fan will not decrease, though it will take the fan longer to reach the maximum speed.

Because as the moment of inertia of the impeller increases its angular acc. will decrease (for the same torque applied), therefore it will take the fan longer to reach its maximum speed. The maximum speed is when the power delivered by the shaft to the impeller will equal the power dissipated through wind resistance, heat etc.

Comment: This is the right answer, idealisticly. In a gravitational field the extra weight will load the bearings, and this will create more friction - and a lower top speed for the same current. But if there is a speed control and enough overhead current, it can still reach top speed since there is feedback.

Answer (score 3):

This will depend on exactly what kind of motor you have.

If your fan is a brushed DC motor, then the fan speed will be slightly lower, since the new impeller is heavier than the old, so there will be slightly greater bearing friction. The added friction will serve as a power loss, and the motor will have to run slightly slower.

If the motor is a brushless motor, the speed is determined by the drive frequency, and as long as the bearing load is not too great the fan speed will remain unchanged.